# How can I take a link that has no title tag and add it based on the link text using regular expressions?

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver

start: `<a href="../index.htm" target="_blank">Home</a>`

I need to be able to use a regular expression in Dreamweaver to search all links on my site (that would be using relative links) to take the link text (Home in this example) and add make that text the title attribute of the link.

finish: `<a href="../index.htm" title="Home" target="_blank">Home</a>`

Comment: Use a capture group to capture the text, and a backreference in the replacement text to insert it. What part of that are you having trouble with? Please show your attempted solution, don't be a help vampire.

Comment: this is my first time attempting a regular expression - so this is all very new to me and have no idea what your comment means..

Comment: Tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(<a (?:(?!title).)*)>(.*?)</a>
```

to match the a tag
and

```
$1 title="$2">$2</a>
```

to replace the string.

[See the DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wS3cC6/1)

Comment: I went to the demo site and this is EXACTLY what i needed - thank you! However, when i place this into Dreamweaver using the Find/Replace and i make sure the Use Regular Expression box is checked, it doesn't find anything...what am i missing?